# Add A 301 Redirect to Codeigniter .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, redirect

I've been trying to set up a redirect for a page that recently moved. The page was originally at `http://example.com/foo/`, but has since moved to `http://example.com/foo/bar/` .

I tried the following rule in my sites `.htaccess` file:

`RedirectMatch 301 ^/foo/$ /foo/bar/`

However going to the url `http://example.com/foo/` resulted in a redirect to the url `http://example.com/foo/bar/?/foo/`. While the url works and the page I want to redirect to loads, I would quite like to get rid of the extra `?/foo/` at the end of the url.

Here is my full .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# add trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [R=301,L]

# allow access to certain directories in webroot
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt|css/|lib/|js/|images/|^(.*)/images)

# gets rid of index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# page redirects
RedirectMatch 301 ^/foo/$ /foo/bar/
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding a `RewriteRrule` to the top of the `.htaccess` after the `RewriteBase /` file solved the problem.

`RewriteRule ^foo/$ /foo/bar [R=301,L]`

Answer (score 0):

I found it easier to redirect from controller instead of .htaccess because .htaccess was adding a querystring at the end.

For example I've put this in my controller's action:

```
if ($this->uri->segment(2)==='old_url') {
  redirect(base_url() . $this->lang->lang() .'/new-url', 'location', 301);
}
```

Comment: This would work, but I feel this should probably be done in the `.htaccess` or apache settings for the site as this will be the first place other developers look if they ever have to work on your site. Putting it in the controller would not be where I would think to find this kind of logic.